# Parse data from uint8array to string to json

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, parsing

Anyone know how to correctly parse from a Uint8Array (which essentially just inherits from Buffer..) to a valid json object?  Using Node.js as the back-end.  I'm uploading a file, and the endpoint receives it as a Uint8Array.  Really this is just a .json file.  So if you take the Array and to .toString(), it spits out content like so:

```
bytes.toString()
""someObject": {
    "foo": "bar",
    "baz": {
        "qux": "quux"
    }
}
"
```

Now, when I attempt to run this through JSON.parse, it fails due to invalid characters.  So I can easily see those with the following:

```
JSON.stringify(bytes.toString())
""\"someObject\": {\r\n\t\"foo\": \"bar\",\r\n\t\"baz\": {\r\n\t\t\"qux\": \"quux\"\r\n\t}\r\n}\r\n""
```

So I have to remove all these tabs and spaces and newlines in order to parse this into an object.  So I do that with the following:

```
JSON.stringify(bytes.toString().replace(/\r/g, '').replace(/\t/g, '').replace(/\n/g, ''))
""\"someObject\": {\"foo\": \"bar\",\"baz\": {\"qux\": \"quux\"}}""
```

Great!  All that extra garbage in there is removed.  So now I can parse this thing.  But wait!  It only parses it right back into a string:

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(bytes.toString().replace(/\r/g, '').replace(/\t/g, '').replace(/\n/g, '')))
""someObject": {"foo": "bar","baz": {"qux": "quux"}}"
```

It's because of the beginning and ending quotes.  So... I suppose I could simply go remove those quotes....

But is there just an easier way to do this?  Seems so hacky to be doing all this replacing and stringifying back to parsing.  What is it that I'm missing here?

All I'm  looking for is an actual object to work with in the following format:

```
{
    "someObject": {
        "foo": "bar",
        "baz": {
            "qux": "quux"
        }
    }
}
```

I know there is something easy here I'm missing.  Please help dumb programmer from smashing face into keyboard! :)

Comment: Is the the exact output of `bytes.toString()`? You'd need a pair of enclosing braces for it to look like valid JSON.

Comment: That was.... I have no words.  That was totally it.  Sometimes you get stuck in a rut and need some outside eyes.  As soon as I used actual valid test files (with the closing braces...), json.parse worked perfectly.  Thank you!

Comment: We have all been there :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add an outer pair of braces to the text encoded in the typed Array:

```
{ 
  "someObject": {
    "foo": "bar",
    "baz": {
      "qux": "quux"
    }
  }
}
```